# Isolating server from home network - Cheapest way

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, wireless-router

**The problem:**

Family members use the `A` network with their devices; I want to connect a Single board computer (SBC) to the internet, but i can not compromise the private network. If my server is taken over, things can go ugly.

**Possible scenarios:**

**Guest Wifi**
It Would be possible to use the guest wifi network with port forwarding , where the pool of addresses is not shared and i can't find the other machines by running nmap -sP 192.168.1.1/24 ;

The downside is limited speeds when i would prefer to have full blown 150 mbps with ethernet cable
(All this assuming the router has secured this functionality, some haven't);
price: wifi dongle 10$

**DMZ**
This one would be obvious for what i've been reading, if i was using wifi on the SBC, but the problem arises when i connect the eth cable, magically i can see everyone in the network again with the router i'm using;
price: *Don't know any cheap home grade router with real DMZ capabilities when using eth.*

**Defining 2 different subnets**
This would set apart the different networks, hopefully not allowing devices from each to connect between them. Unfortunately my router is a crappy one full of limitations imposed by the ISP, not giving me routing options; 
price: 30$-50$ *Any cheap router with routing capabilities*

**Run a Virtual Machine**
Not practical considering the SBC has a weak A20 processor under the hood.

One of the reasons i'm trying to configure the setting on my own (instead of buying an hosting account) is to learn, so if i have made any incorrect assumptions above in my statements, please correct me. Thank you!

Comment: You could get a second router that you connect to the first. Then you connect the SBC to the first router and everything else in your home to the second.

Comment: The only way to have an isolated network is to have two networks.  One connected to the internet and one that isn't

Comment: @SpiderPig Didn't thought of that, and it seems a good option. Any downsides to this approach you suggest? Maybe bottle necking the speeds for the whole family, but they don't need it fast anyway!

Comment: @Ramhound I understand that, but is there any option that would make things a little bit more secure, and still have a doorway (port 80 at least) to the internet?

Comment: Why should that bottleneck the speed? As long as the second router is not a really slow and cheap model it should be fine.

Comment: Spend the money and get something proper if "..you can not compromise the private network."  realistically you could spend $200-$300 on some ubiquiti hardware and have some real enterprise features.  Also, you can setup a PF sense box of something on some legacy hardware and some NICs; although power vs performance is killer compared to purpose built hardware.